# Java how to make a circle slowly move around?

Tags: java

Hello I have an app where there are circles floating around. At the moment the don't float around, which is the problem. I want them to slowly move around in random directions. How can I do this? 
Here is my circle class:

```
    public class data {

    public int x,y, size,id;

    public data(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        size = new Random().nextInt(50);
        id = new Random().nextInt(10);

    }

    public void tick(){
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(38,127,0));
        g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(x, y, size, size);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+move

Answer (score 0):

You can have a very random movement by adding a random value to x and to y every tick:

```
private Random random = new Random();

public void tick() {
    x = x + random.nextFloat();
    y = y + random.nextFloat();
}
```

This will result in a very fuzzy motion.

Another option is to have 2 variables: motionX and motionY. Those get added to x and y every tick, after which you add random values to motionX and motionY:

```
private Random random = new Random();
private float xMotion = 0f, yMotion = 0f;
private float factor = 0.5f;    //just a value to reduce speed

private void tick() {
    x = x + xMotion;
    y = y + yMotion;
    xMotion = xMotion + random.nextFloat() * factor;
    yMotion = yMotion + random.nextFloat() * factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you messed up which one you should random, you random selected a size and the id(what is this for anyways?), not the x,y value. Also, I don't know why, but it seems that the render program must be called paint.